# Firebase Crashes doesn't show in Firebase Console at all

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

The app I am developing is linked to a project in Firebase Console. I have included 'google-services.json' under the 'app' folder too.

My Top Level build.gradle is:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

My App Level build.gradle is:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.8.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I know that latest 'firebase-crash' is 10.0.1 which requires an updated Google Repository and Google Play Services. However, I am able to use same firebase-crash on another app I am making. I am a little short on internet pack, i can't update yet.

I use following snippet in `onCreate()` of MainActivity to cause a test crash:

```
FirebaseCrash.log(TAG + ": Test Log"));
FirebaseCrash.report(new Exception("Test Exception"));
```

I checked 'google-services.json' too for correct mobile_sdk_id, it matches perfectly. My package name matches with firebase project too.

I don't do anything with Firebase Analytics.

Following is logcat output:

```
20:09:07.830 D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
20:09:07.915 D/FA: Connected to remote service
20:09:07.915 V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 3
20:09:10.340 D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 301K, 12% free 11312K/12807K, paused 45ms+3ms, total 167ms
20:09:12.995 V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
20:13:29.480 V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 261701
20:13:29.480 V/FA: Using measurement service
20:13:29.480 V/FA: Connecting to remote service
20:13:29.485 V/FA: Activity paused, time: 31073604
20:13:29.485 D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _si=-207754800234984953, _et=261701, _sc=MainActivity}]
20:13:29.675 D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 612K, 14% free 11339K/13127K, paused 31ms+64ms, total 187ms
20:13:29.675 V/FA: Using measurement service
20:13:29.690 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
20:13:29.690 D/FA: Connected to remote service
20:13:29.695 V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
20:13:34.745 V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
20:26:19.835 D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 630K, 14% free 11302K/13127K, paused 19ms+2ms, total 135ms
```

Its been 5 hours since i am trying to see Errors on Firebase Console. I have tried opening and closing my app for more than 20 times.

*How do i know FirebaseCrash has been enabled?
When will Errors show up in console?
Am i doing something wrong?*

**Edit**:

1. There is no `V/FirebaseCrash:` message in logcat.
2. Following does not appear in logcat:

   ```
   FirebaseCrash.logcat(0, TAG, "Test Logcat 0");
   FirebaseCrash.logcat(1, TAG, "Test Logcat 1");
   ```
3. There are some lines printed by FirebaseCrash before debugger has attached:

   ```
   12-11 22:27:09.950 I/FirebaseCrash: FirebaseCrash reporting initialized com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbks@424d3e68
   12-11 22:27:09.950 I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
   ```
4. Updated Firebase-Crash to 10.0.1 and other SDK tools. No change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so ashamed to know that my laptop's date was one day late. As soon as i corrected the date, results started to show in console. My problem is solved now.